# Htaccess rewrite condition for files with no file extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite condition for specific file types like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*(\/|.htaccess|.htpasswd|.ini|.log)$
```

This works fine for files with those file extensions however I can't figure out how to make it also match files with no extension.

Eg. `cats.com/regularfile.ini` and `cats.com/regularfile` should both trigger the condition.

Any ideas?

I am fine if the no extension condition needs to be separate but it should trigger whether the file actually exists or not as my current rule does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to make it also match files with no extension.

You may use it like this:

```sh
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:[^.]+|.*(/|\.(?:htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log)))$
```

`[^.]+` match 1 or more of any character that doesn't have dot.

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering why the `?:` was added in front of htaccess as it seems to work the same without it.

Comment: Yes it will work without `?:` also. `?:` makes it a non-capturing group instead of a capturing one. It reduces overall memory footprint but as you noted `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^.]+|.*(/|\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log)))$` will also work.

Comment: would splitting them into separate rewrite conditions give the same performance boost? or would that make it slower since the regex function is called twice in the event the first doesn't match?

Comment: Better to keep it in single `RewriteCond` as suggested for best performance

Comment: Unfortunately, this rule also blocks the base URL of `/`. Still, a great answer thank you but should probably be noted that it will break your home page without addjustment.

Comment: I have tested this before posting. This condition doesn't match landing page URI which is just a single `/`. It will of course match `/home` or `/anything`

Comment: Yes your right I made a mistake.  It was caused by my original rule.